# OGRFeature set Multiple fields

Tags: gdal, wfs, c++

To start off with:

Using Gdal compiled with Xerces

Coding in C++ with the QT Creator version 5.4.1

So my problem is I'm trying to use Gdal to create my own Esri shapefile, I get a strange runtime error when trying to add multiple fields

Example:

```
    // Create a ogr feeature
    OGRFeature* ogr_feature;
    // Set a bunch of fields
    ogr_feature->SetField("Blah","Blah");
    ogr_feature->SetField("Foo","Foo");
    ogr_feature->SetField("Bar","Bar");
    ogr_feature->SetField("Test","Test");
```

When I run the program once it hits this part it gives out this error message:

Error :1 Invalid Index -1

I'm not too sure what's causing this. I've tried taking out all but 1 and that's fine doesn't give me any errors. But more than 1 it throws that error.

Anyone know how to fix this/ why its doing it?

Comment: Never used that but in a similar library my questions would be: Does the feature have a schema that supports those fields? Does the feature have a geometry?

Comment: Yeah I set the Geometry on the Feature before I do SetField, Gdal supports custom fields, just gets saved as GML/XML or into Esri shapefile.  Other WFS have this ability to have many fields but not sure why it won't work for me.

Comment: @bugmenot makes a good question about the schema. By looking at the documentation http://www.gdal.org/classOGRFeature.html#a4abbe118cc2f3e48bbac7f710b71b531 the first parameter is the index of the field and I do not understand how even a single SetField("Blah","Blah") can ever work for you.

Comment: You need to create a feature definition that defines the schema.  See the example at the bottom of this page:

http://gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out:
[http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/~plewis/geogg122_current/_build/html/ChapterX_GDAL/OGR_Python.html](http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eplewis/geogg122_current/_build/html/ChapterX_GDAL/OGR_Python.html)

In python, you have to CreateField first.

So the layer you are creating a feature for needs to have CreateField used to add a field definition.